# Javascript Regex for capturing variables in curved brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that is being fed into a JavaScript function and I need to pull the variables out of it.

```
var str = "heres:a:func('var1', 'var2', 'var3', 2)"
```

I'm getting close, but would like to do it with one regex.

```
str.match(/\((.*)\)/)[1].split(/\s*,\s*/)
```

Results should look like this:

```
['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 2]
```

Comment: What's the problem with just using two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

[Regex101 Link](https://regex101.com/r/aG7iZ5/1)

This does not include the quotes by the way, you can add those optionally if you want.

```
var pattern = /(\w+)(?!.*\()(?=.*\))/g;
var str = "heres:a:func('var1', 'var2', 'var3', 2)";
var matches = str.match(pattern);
console.log(matches); //['var1','var2','var3','2']
```

This basically searches for a word character group, and then does a negative and positive lookahead.
Basically

```
(?!.*\()
```

says that I want this to NOT be before any number of characters plus a ( character and

```
(?=.*\))
```

says that i WANT this to be before any number of characters and a ) character.

Then the capturing group is at the beginning, so you could replace (\w+) with ([\'\w]+) if you wanted to keep the quotes (which I don't think you would right)

---

**Edit:**  To include spaces in your strings, you can do something like this:

```
var pattern = /([\w]+\s[\w]+|\w+)(?!.*\()(?=.*\))/g
```

But that will not capture trailing white space, just spaces surrounded by 2 word types (a-Z0-1).  Also that only will allow 1 space in the word, so if you need multiples, you'd have to check for that as well.  You could modify it to check for any number of word characters or spaces between 2 valid word characters.

For Multiple Spaces:

```
var pattern = /([\w]+[\s\w]*[\w]+|\w+)(?!.*\()(?=.*\))/g
```

Includes 1 Space:  [Regex101 Link](https://regex101.com/r/aG7iZ5/2)

Includes Multiple Spaces:  [Regex101 Link](https://regex101.com/r/aG7iZ5/3)

**Edit2:**
And just as a final one, if you REALLY want to add a bunch of spaces throughout, you can do this one:

Includes Multiple Spaces, Multiple Times:  [Regex101 Link](https://regex101.com/r/aG7iZ5/4)

```
/([\w]+[\s\w]+[\w]+|\w+)(?!.*\()(?=.*\))/g
```

Comment: What about if there were spaces in the variables: heres:a:func('var 1', 'var 2', 'var 3', 2) ?

Comment: If you wanted to include spaces, it'd get a bit more complex.  You can't just use the word spacing then.  I'll update the regex.

Answer (score 1):

This should do `('\w+'|\d+)` it captures words (`\w` = alphanumeric and hyphen) between single quote or (`|`) numeric unquoted values.

See the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/vI5rK5/1)

For a code exemple:

```
var str = "heres:a:func('var1', 'var2', 'var3', 2)"
var reg=new RegExp("('\\w+'|\\d+)", "g");
var i= 0;
var arr = [];
str.replace(reg,function(m,group) {arr[i++]=group})
```

console.log(arr) gives:

```
["'var1'", "'var2'", "'var3'", "2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one line, but still 2 regexps: 1) remove all up to the opening `(` and the closing `)`, then split on the commas with optional whitespace. This way we'll get all the `var`s, regardless of how many there are variables.

```js
var str = "heres:a:func('var1', 'var2', 'var3', 2)";
alert(str.replace(/.*\(|\s*\)\s*$/g, '').split(/\s*,\s*/));
```

Also, you might try a kind of a fancy regex, but it is not that safe (only works if you have correctly formatted data):

```js
var re = /('[^']*?'|\b\d+\b),?(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*\)$)/g; 
var str = 'heres:a:func23(\'var1\', \'var2\', \'var3\', 2, \'2345\')';
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += m[1] + "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Comment: Did you have time to check my approach? Actually, I doubt the single-regex solution is viable in JavaScript. Its regex engine is very poor in features :(

Comment: @Tensibai: what if there is a space? Or a plus or minus? Your regex won't match special characters, Unicode letters, etc.

Comment: Just add the allowed chars in the left side within a class like [\w_@$£€%+~&]+ instead of only \w+ and it will do. If you really wish to allow all but single quote (ending of var) use a negative class [^']+ to match anything but single quote

Comment: Anyway, you cannot be sure you are inside an opening and closing bracket, as in JS there is no \G operator.

Comment: Yes, but the blocking part is the lack of lookbehind, not of \G. Anyway if you really want to ensure the brackets, this can be done by building a pattern in the function callback using the two args like `m.match(".*\(.*"+group+".*\).*")`. But this is guessing what the OP input could be, and I don't wish to use divination on requirements ;)

Answer (score 0):

As i can't add a comment i post a answer.

```js
var str = "heres:a:func('var1', 'var2', 'var3', 2)"
var args = /\(\s*([^)]+?)\s*\)/.exec(str);
if (args[1]) {
   args = args[1].split(/\s*,\s*/);
   console.log(args);
   alert(args);
}
```

or try it out here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/oz3Ljfe1/3/